# If(something) re-do the for loop

Tags: java

This one is very simple and basic, but for some reason I cant get it right. So I'm making a for loop and inside the for loop generating random numbers, but I want to eliminate some numbers by redoing the for loop when those numbers come up. how should I do it and whats my mistake. Thank you in advance.

How I did it:

```
int[] array= new int[6];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   Random rand = new Random();
   int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
   if(n==5 || n==9 || n==13){
      i--;
      return;
   }
   array[i]=n;
}
```

Comment: change `return` to `continue`

Comment: Your mistake is calling `return;` when you don't intend to return. Did you mean `continue;`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to *"re-do"* the for loop? As in if you hit a number start the loop over (*which can possibly be an infinite loop or unnecessary long loop*) Can you clarify what you want exactly? To me it looks like you just don't want to include `5`, `9`, and `13`.

Comment: Thank you for help `continue` worked

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting post.  Just want to chime in and share what my first instinct is.  Perhaps it is not conventional.

There is *no reason* to roll again if you hit upon 5, 9, 13.  The approach can be deterministic

Algorithm:

1. Choose a number **R** between 1-47 (the numbers 1-4, 6-8, 10-12, 14-50 are all equally probable)
2. If R == 5 then R = 48
3. else if R == 9 then R = 49
4. else if R == 13 then R = 50

This can easily be made into a function where you pass a set of unwanted numbers.

Comment: Interesting answer

Comment: technically that's completely random, but because I'm using this for a school project I thought my teacher might say 'It's not random enough'. But thank you anyways.

Comment: It would be a shame if a teacher would argue against this approach.  This answer calculates the variable with equal probability, and the most efficiency.  But I understand.  Good luck in your studies, and hopefully you learned something by this exercise.

Comment: makes no sense to me

Comment: I'd be happy to explain if you provide a bit of insight to what doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

I think the cleanest way would be to have an inner loop that loops until you get an acceptable number. That way the inner loop could be later factored into a function if necessary. I also moved the random number generator initialization out of the loop, since I assume that's what was intended.

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  int n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
  while (n == 5 || n == 9 || n == 13) {
    n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
  }
  array[i] = n;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. What if (**extremely unlike, but *possible***) you are always hitting the 5, or 9, or 13?

Comment: @zlakad Then you should invest in lottery tickets. At any rate, `java.util.Random` is a PRNG, so it will never get stuck.

Comment: Yep, but I think it can be avoided in this case. E.g. make a Collection with all Integers except 5, 9, 13. Call `Collections.shuffle()`, and take the first `array.lenght` elements

Comment: It is a matter of efficiency... Suppose that you have to chose some set of randoms in the way these are set of very narrow sub-set of the other set of  randoms?

Comment: I agree with @zlakad's point here, and is the main reason why I included my answer. If essentially OP doesn't want to pick: 5, 9, or 13 from their choices of random numbers then there isn't a reason to include those numbers as choices in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could use a *while-loop*:

```
int[] array= new int[6];
int i = 0;
while(i<array.length){
   Random rand = new Random();
   int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
   if(n!=5 && n!=9 && n!=13){
       array[i++] = n;  
   }
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat, editted. Of course, you have to wrapped it with a main function and import java.util.*

Answer (score 1):

On thing you could do is generate a list of numbers from `[1, .., 50]` and remove the numbers you don't want from that list: `[5, 9, 13]`. Like so:

```
List<Integer> unwatedNums = Arrays.asList(5, 9, 13);
List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 50).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
list.removeAll(unwatedNums);
```

Now instead you can safely grab a random element from that list without having it to unnecessarily get a new random number in some cases:

```
int[] array= new int[6];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    array[i]=list.get((new Random()).nextInt(list.size()));
}
```

Comment: @Antimony I'm not sure what you mean by: *"random numbers without replacement"* in your first comment. What's the issue with this method exactly?

Comment: You could also do a `Collections.shuffle()` on list and then just take the first six elements

Comment: @ScaryWombat That would limit it to be a set of uniquely picked numbers, where I see no reason in OP's code that a repeated random number is considered invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to make sure you don't generate the numbers you don't want - you can adjust your range depending on how many numbers you want to exclude.

This function will give you a random number for `lowRange` to `highRange` (both ends included), without any of the numbers specified in `without`:

```
public static int randomWithout(Random rand, int lowRange, int highRange, int... without) {
    int range = highRange - lowRange + 1 - without.length;
    int result = rand.nextInt(range) + lowRange;
    for (int i = 0; i < without.length; i++) {
        if (result >= without[i]) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can then use this function like this:

```
int[] array = new int[6];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    array[i] = randomWithout(rand, 1, 50, 5, 9, 13);
}
```

The big advantage is deterministic running time - using a `while` loop while you get a number that you don't want could theoretically run forever.